# Dynamic Number of UILabels in custom tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I created a custom tableview cell and I want to display some strings in that cell. I fetch strings from backend thus I don't know how many labels I needed. I tried to concat strings in one label and implemented like below however I want to display strings with different attributes after char ":".

```
for (AttributesModel* attribute in model.attributes) {
    NSString *attributeName = attribute.name;
    attributeString = [[attributeString stringByAppendingString: attributeName] mutableCopy];
    attributeString = [[attributeString stringByAppendingString: @" : "] mutableCopy];
    for (NSDictionary *value in attribute.options) {
        attributeString = [[attributeString stringByAppendingString: [value objectForKey:@"name"] ] mutableCopy];
        attributeString = [[attributeString stringByAppendingString: @", "] mutableCopy];
    }
    attributeString = [[attributeString stringByAppendingString: @"\n"] mutableCopy];
}
```

I could not change attributes of strings thats located after char ":". 
Are there any way to do that? Can I create dynamic number of labels in cell or only change attributes of strings that are only located after ":" ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to change the attributes such as formatting of a section of text within a UILabel. You can do this by:

1. Creating an attributed, mutable copy of your string (a.k.a converting an NSString into an NSMutableAttributedString).
2. Changing the attributes to parts of this copy.
3. Setting your label's `attributedText` property to your attributed string.

```
NSString *myString = @"This is my string";
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myString];
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [attributedString mutableCopy];

// The range of text to change, i.e. start from the 5th index
// (starting from 0 like arrays), and continue for 2 characters:
NSRange rangeOfSecondWord = NSMakeRange(5, 2);

// The list of attributes to apply to that range:
NSDictionary *myAttributes = @{
                               NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor],
                               };

// Actually apply the attributes:
[mutableAttributedString setAttributes:myAttributes range:rangeOfSecondWord];

// Set the text of the label to the attributed string:
myLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString;
```

For a list of attributes that you can set in your dictionary, see the [Character Attributes reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1652619-character_attributes?language=objc).

Since you're downloading your strings, you may not know the range beforehand. Since you're concatenating them, here is how you can find the range dynamically:

```
NSString *stringOne = @"My name is ";
NSString *stringTwo = @"John Citizen";
NSString *joinedStrings = [stringOne stringByAppendingString:stringTwo];

NSRange rangeOfStringTwo = [joinedStrings rangeOfString:stringTwo];
```